# Prevent execution of non-SGE programs

Tags: job-scheduling, system-administration, sungridengine

From the point of view of the system administration of an SGE node, is it possible to force users to run long-running programs through qsub instead of running it stand-alone?

The problem is that the same machine is acting as the control node and the computation node.  So, I can't distinguish a long-running program from a user who is compiling with "gcc".  Ideally, I would like to force users to submit long-running jobs (i.e., more than an hour) through qsub.  I don't even mind being a bit mean and killing jobs that have run longer than an hour but weren't submitted through qsub.

Until now,  all that I can do is send e-mails out asking users to "Please use qsub!"...

I've looked through the SGE configuration and nothing seems relevant.  But maybe I've just missed something...any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about your setup, but I'm assuming users are submitting jobs by logging into what is also a computation node. Here are some ideas, best to worst:

1. Obviously, the best thing is to have a separate control node for users.
2. Barring that, run a resource-limited VM as the control node.
3. Configure user-level resource limits (e.g. **ulimit**) on the nodes. You can restrict CPU, memory, and process usage, which are probably what you care about rather than clock time.

It sounds like the last one may be best for you. It's not hard, either.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!  Sorry if I was not very clear.  Suppose there is a computational intensive program "foo".  I don't want to limit the resources taken up by "foo" by "user A".  I would rather they run foo as "qsub ./script-to-run-foo" instead of "./foo".  Using ulimit would limit how their programs are run.  I'm not worried about that, but more worried of users "jumping the queue" [of queued jobs by other users].